# How to stop for loop from erasing correct guesses for hangman?

Tags: java

The following is a hangman problem for the word sponge.
When the user enters the correct characters (s,p,o,n,g,e) the array hidden[] updates correctly (replaces a _ with the correct char).

However, when the user enters the incorrect char, it displays the hidden[] with all _ _ _ _ _ _

Any tips are appreciated! Thanks

```
package javaapplication3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String secretWord = "sponge";
        int lettersLeft = secretWord.length();
        int attempts = 6;
        int position = 0; //Index of found character in string
        char[] hidden = new char[secretWord.length()]; //Array of hidden chars

        //Display initial hidden array
        for(int i=0; i < secretWord.length(); i++)
        {
            hidden[i] = '_';
            System.out.print(hidden[i] + " ");
        }

        do{
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Attempts left = " + attempts);
            System.out.println("Enter a letter to guess the word: ");

            //User enters character
            Scanner scan2 = new Scanner (System.in);
            char test = scan2.next().charAt(0);

            //Search string secretWord if char test is in it
            if(secretWord.contains(Character.toString(test)))
            {
                position = secretWord.indexOf(test) +1;
                //System.out.println("Letter is in position: " + position);
                lettersLeft--;
            }
            else
            {
                position = 0;
                attempts--;
            }

            //Update hidden array with _ or correct char
            for(int i=0; i < secretWord.length(); i++)
            {
                if (position == 0)
                {
                    hidden[i] = '_';
                }
                else if (position != 0)
                {
                    hidden[position-1] = test;
                }
                System.out.print(hidden[i] + " ");
            }
        } while(lettersLeft != 0 && attempts != 0);

        if(attempts == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("You lost! The correct word was: " + secretWord);
        }

        if(lettersLeft == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Good job! You won!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you run through your code in a debugger to watch its behavior as you enter the input that produces unexpected results?  This is the way to approach this problem.  You shouldn't have to ask other programmers to fix your logic for you.  You should be able to figure it out yourself. - also, I expect we'd all appreciate it if you formatted your code with proper indention to make it easier to read.

Comment: I fixed your formatting for you this time.

Comment: A nit pick issue, but `else if (position != 0)` can just be `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rewrite the whole `hidden` array with `_` in case of incorrect input - in the same loop where you display it's contents. I don't know why you do that.

What you want to do is only update correct guesses in `hidden`, and leave it as is in case of incorrect guesses.

e.g. replace this:

```
//Update hidden array with _ or correct char
for(int i=0; i < secretWord.length(); i++)
{
    if (position == 0)
    {
    hidden[i] = '_';
    }
    else if (position != 0)
    {
       hidden[position-1] = test;     
    }
    System.out.print(hidden[i] + " ");
}
```

with this:

```
if (position != 0) {
    hidden[position - 1] = test;
}
for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
    System.out.print(hidden[i] + " ");
}
```